# USB doesn't appear and I'm not able to mount it

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive, fdisk

I'm trying to open an USB device but when I connect it, it doesn't appear.

If I execute `ls /dev/sd*` without connect my device the following results appears:

`/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3`

If I execute the same command when I connect it the following results appears:

`/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3   /dev/sdb`

With that, I supose that my device is `/dev/sdb`.

The problem is that if I execute `lsblk` to check the blockdevices and the file systems that are assigned to those block device, it doesn't appears on the list, so I'm not able to mount it.

Any idea?

Best Regards,

Comment: Just after you connect the disk, type the `dmesg` command. It will show you what Linux thinks is happening.

Comment: Do you have any software that listens directly for USB events? Like Virtualbox?